# Solving a limit with different terms to the power n using definitions

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

How to solve for the limit of 
$$\left(\frac{n^3}{2^n} + \frac{3}{4}\right)^n $$
using definitions.

I have seen a lot of methods using the natural number and logarithms, but we can only use rules of sequences and definitions.

I started by attempting to separate the inside but don’t really know what to do / where to go.

*(note: we can make use of a few standard null sequences, algebra of limits, sandwich theorem)*

Comment: What sorts of things are you allowed to use, then? Are you saying it really has to be an $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof? Can you at least use results like $\lim(x_n+y_n) = \lim(x_n) + \lim(y_n)$?

Comment: Apologies, I have just edited the question. We can use algebra of limits.

Comment: This is not about "solving for" a limit; this is about _evaluating_ a limit. You may _solve for_ a variable in an equation, but that's not what this is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence $\left(\frac{n^3}{2^n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is decreasing if we restrict it to $\mathbb N\setminus\{1,2,3\}$. It turns out that $\frac{15^3}{2^{15}}<\frac3{20}$ and that therefore $\frac{15^3}{2^{15}}+\frac34<\frac{18}{20}=\frac9{10}$. So,$$n\geqslant15\implies\left(\frac{n^3}{2^n}\right)^n<\left(\frac9{10}\right)^n=\frac1{\left(\frac{10}9\right)^n}=\frac1{\left(1+\frac19\right)^n}<\frac9n.$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I can continue from this. I had a question however; can I not say $\frac{n^3}{2^n}$ tends to 0. Hence, the limit of $\frac{n^3}{2^n} + \frac{3}{4} = 0 + $ limit of 3/4. Since we know $\frac{n^3}{2^n} + \frac{3}{4} \leq 3/4$, then $\left(\frac{n^3}{2^n} + \frac{3}{4} \right )^n \leq \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n$ which we know tends to 0, and then use the Squeeze Theorem?

Comment: Sure, but if you can use the squeeze theorem, then why did you write in the title of your question “using definitions”?

Comment: Apologies, I edited the question later to add some things we may use. So is the math of what I proposed all correct / valid?

Comment: Almost. Actually, we **never** have $\frac{n^3}{2^n}+\frac34\leqslant\frac34.$ But you can say that, since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^3}{2^n}=0$, then $\frac{n^3}{2^n}+\frac34<\frac45$ if $n$ is large enough.

Comment: In your answer when you say for $n \geq 15$, is there a specific method to use to calculate what n we can use without a calculator?

Comment: Yes:$$\frac{15^3}{2^{15}}=\left(\frac{15}{2^5}\right)^3=\left(\frac12\right)^3=\frac18<\frac3{20}.$$

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. Is the choice of 15 arbitrary / trial and error?

Comment: Trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\left(\frac{n^3}{2^n} + \frac{3}{4}\right)^n =e^{n\log\left(\frac{n^3}{2^n} + \frac{3}{4}\right)} \to 0$$

indeed since $\frac{n^3}{2^n}\to 0$

$$n\log\left(\frac{n^3}{2^n} + \frac{3}{4}\right) \to \infty\cdot \log \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)=-\infty$$

As an alternative since $\frac{n^3}{2^n}\to 0$, we have that for some $n_0$ for all $n\ge n_0 \implies \frac{n^3}{2^n}\le \frac18$ then for $n\ge n_0$

$$\left(\frac{n^3}{2^n} + \frac{3}{4}\right)^n \le\left(\frac18+\frac34\right)^n=\left(\frac78\right)^n \to 0$$

Answer (score 0):

Finding the limit is very straight forward.

The inner function approaches  $3/4$ because $$\frac {n^3}{2^n}\to 0$$

Therefore the sequence approaches $0$

Proof by definition is complicated if by difinitin you mean  to show  for a given $\epsilon $ finding a natural number $N$  such that $$n\ge N \implies \left(\frac{n^3}{2^n} + \frac{3}{4}\right)^n <\epsilon$$

We can approach solving it in two steps, one for the inner sequence and  one for the outer one and somehow combine them.